# script to convert Csv to xml

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

**Need to process the file using for loop**

I have written below code to convert csv to xml. Here have written separate tag for each column.
In input file have column from 1 to 278. In output file need to have tag from A1 to A278,

Code :

```
file_in="Prepaid_plan_voucher.csv"
file_out="Prepaid_plan_voucher.xml"
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > $file_out
#echo '<Customers>' >> $file_out
echo '  <TariffRecords>' >> $file_out
echo '  <Tariff>' >> $file_out
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
#  echo '  <TariffRecords>' >> $file_out
#  echo '  <Tariff>' >> $file_out
  echo '    <A1>'${arry[0]}'</A1>' >> $file_out
  echo '    <A2>'${arry[1]}'</A2>' >> $file_out
  echo '    <A3>'${arry[2]}'</A3>' >> $file_out
#  echo '  </TariffRecords>' >> $file_out
#  echo '  </Tariff>' >> $file_out
done < $file_in
#echo '</Customers>' >> $file_out
echo '  <TariffRecords>' >> $file_out
echo '  <Tariff>' >> $file_out
```

Sample Input file.(this is a sample record in actual input file will contain 278 columns).
If input file has two or three records, same needs to be appended in one XML file.

```
name,Tariff Summary,Record ID No.,Operator Name,Circle (Service Area),list
Prepaid Plan Voucher,test_All calls 2p/s,TT07PMPV0188,Ta Te,Gu,
Prepaid Plan Voucher,test_All calls 3p/s,TT07PMPV0189,Ta Te,HR,
```

Sample output file

    
The above two TariffRecords, tariff will be hard coded at the beginning and end of xml file.

```
<TariffRecords>
<Tariff>
<A1>Prepaid Plan Voucher</A1>
<A2>test_All calls 2p/s</A2>
<A3>TT07PMPV0188</A3>
<A4>Ta Te</A4>
<A5>Gu</A5>
<A6></A6>
<Tariff>
<Tariff>
<A1>Prepaid Plan Voucher</A1>
<A2>test_All calls 3p/s</A2>
<A3>TT07PMPV0189</A3>
<A4>Ta Te</A4>
<A5>HR</A5>
<A6></A6>
<Tariff>
<TariffRecords>
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I would recommend using `XSLT 2.0 or 3.0` to convert `CSV` to `XML` format

Comment: Hi @Orel..need to convert the input csv file into xml using  shell script using for loop..as i have column from column1 to column 278(need to ignore header) with tags in xml file from A1 to A278

Comment: @as7951, why shoud `A6></A6>` be empty?

Comment: @Allan +1 for XSLT!

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45420535/1745001 and start reading Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @hradecek - I added an XSLT example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though, this is not the most elegant solution, but I think you just want to simply do this, if I understand correctly. So doing as many modifications to your code as possible I got:

```
NUM_OF_COLS=5
echo '<TariffRecords>' >> $file_out
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
  tariff="  <Tariff>\n"
  for i in $(seq 0 $NUM_OF_COLS); do
    tariff="${tariff}    <A$i>${arry[$i]}</A$i>\n"
  done
  tariff="${tariff}  </Tariff>"
  echo -e ${tariff} >> $file_out
done < <(tail -n +1 $file_in)
echo '</TariffRecords>' >> $file_out
```

**Things to note:**

We are skipping CSV header by:

```
<(tail -n +1 $file_in)
```

Generate "foeach" cycle in range from `0` to `$NUM_OF_COLS`, which represents column's indices by:

```
$(seq 0 $NUM_OF_COLS)
```

Append string by:

```
tariff="${tariff}......"
```

Using

```
echo -e ...
```

in order to preserve new lines and nice formatting, but you might use another bash utility like `xmllint` in order to pretty formatting.

**EDIT: For mulitple files**

In order to process multiple files, replace hardcoded:

```
file_in="Prepaid_plan_voucher.csv"
file_out="Prepaid_plan_voucher.xml"
```

by

```
file_in="$1" # Take the name as an argument from command line
file_out="${1%.csv}.xml" # Remove csv suffix and append xml
```

and run the script from command line for every `csv` file, e.g. like this:

```
$ for f in $(ls *.csv); do ./ourscript.sh $f; done
```

Comment: @hradecek...Able to create xml file but not able to read it as XML file.
It is coming as simple text file only when i am trying to open in windows in browser..
Please help

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I had `<TariffRecords>` instead of closing tag `</TariffRecords>`. Fixed. btw: XML (data representation) is usually stored in a text file.

Comment: Hi @hradecek..Can you tell me how can i modify this code so that i can pick multiple csv file with *.csv and then generate separate xml for each file

Comment: @as7951 - I have edited an answer with one possible solution (the least "obtrusive" meaning *It will do the job*).

Answer (score 2):

Since it was mentioned in the comments, here's an option using XSLT 3.0.

The processor I tested with is [Saxon-HE 9.8](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.8HE) and is run with a java command line. It should be easy to incorporate into a shell script to process multiple files.

**CSV Input** (added an additional row to show handling of another empty entry and a quoted entry that contains commas that aren't separators)

```
name,Tariff Summary,Record ID No.,Operator Name,Circle (Service Area),list
Prepaid Plan Voucher,test_All calls 2p/s,TT07PMPV0188,Ta Te,Gu,
Prepaid Plan Voucher,test_All calls 3p/s,TT07PMPV0189,Ta Te,HR,
Prepaid Plan Voucher,,TT07PMPV0190,Ta Te,DH,"some,comma,separated,list"
```

**XSLT 3.0**

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="csv-uri"/>
  <xsl:param name="csv-encoding" select="'UTF-8'"/>

  <xsl:template name="init">
    <TariffRecords>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="unparsed-text-available($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)">
          <xsl:call-template name="csv2xml"/>                               
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:variable name="error">
            <xsl:text>Error reading "{$csv-uri}" (encoding "{$csv-encoding}").</xsl:text>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$error"/></xsl:message>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </TariffRecords>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="csv2xml">
    <xsl:variable name="csv_content" select="unparsed-text($csv-uri, $csv-encoding)"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="$csv_content" regex="\r?\n">
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><!--ignore header-->
          <Tariff>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="concat(.,',')" regex='"([^"]*)",?|([^,]+),?'>
              <!--group 1 is wrapped in quotes-->
              <!--group 2 is not wrapped quotes-->
              <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="A{position()}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="(regex-group(1),regex-group(2))" separator=""/>
                </xsl:element>
              </xsl:matching-substring>
              <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="A{position()}"/>
              </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
          </Tariff>          
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>      
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command line** ([see here](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/) for more info on running Saxon from the command line)

```
java -cp "C:/apps/SaxonHE9-8-0-11J/saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:init -xsl:"csv2xml.xsl" -o:"output.xml" csv-uri="input.csv"
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TariffRecords>
   <Tariff>
      <A1>Prepaid Plan Voucher</A1>
      <A2>test_All calls 2p/s</A2>
      <A3>TT07PMPV0188</A3>
      <A4>Ta Te</A4>
      <A5>Gu</A5>
      <A6/>
   </Tariff>
   <Tariff>
      <A1>Prepaid Plan Voucher</A1>
      <A2>test_All calls 3p/s</A2>
      <A3>TT07PMPV0189</A3>
      <A4>Ta Te</A4>
      <A5>HR</A5>
      <A6/>
   </Tariff>
   <Tariff>
      <A1>Prepaid Plan Voucher</A1>
      <A2/>
      <A3>TT07PMPV0190</A3>
      <A4>Ta Te</A4>
      <A5>DH</A5>
      <A6>some,comma,separated,list</A6>
   </Tariff>
</TariffRecords>
```

Comment: @as7951 - this is more suitable solution than mine. +1